# Can't find or buy Spell Tome: Invisibility

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm having troubles finding the invisibility spell tome at all. I have Illusion at  level 90 and I went to the illusion trainer in the College of Winterhold and he wasn't selling it either.  I have checked all over the internet and I coudn't find anything else on how to get it, so where am I supposed to find it? I'd like to know where to buy it as it seems nobody is selling it.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm playing as a Dark Elf illusion thief, but the twist is I can't use weapons so I need invisibility.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [UESP](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Invisibility_%28spell%29#Invisibility) (A source I prefer to the various wikias), the only guaranteed source for the Invisibility spell is Drevis Neloren, who will sell it to the player once their Illusion skill is 65+.

It is possible that if your Illusion skill has *just* reached that threshold, Drevis will not have it in stock. If this appears to be the case, simply trigger a merchant restock (by waiting 2 days), and he should have every Expert Illusion spell (of which, Invisibility is one).

Beyond that, the console commands in [Trent's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243458/336) will give you immediate results.